# how to kill mysql processes

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, process, ps

My docker-compose command won't run because I have these processes running:

```
$ sudo lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN | grep sql
mysqld          113           _mysql   19u     IPv6 0xd0786f05dec2ff3f         0t0      TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
mysqld          113           _mysql   22u     IPv6 0xd0786f05dec789ff         0t0      TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
```

Every time I kill the process listed, it starts up again with a new PID.

I've already uninstalled it:

```
$ brew uninstall mysql
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
```

How can I totally and permanently kill this?

I've tried

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld stop
```

and

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

When I try:

```
sudo mysql.server stop
```

It shows:

ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

but I still see new processes running for mysqld

Comment: did you figure out ?

Comment: @KayaToast - no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Search process by port `sudo lsof -i tcp:3306` 
(2) Kill by userid `pkill -u UID`

Answer (score 1):

Find out how mysqld is being spawned (like daemontools) and stop it from there. Or
Try `killall mysqld`